# Can I give an ng-form a name that I can check with $pristine?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I looked at the documentation for ng-form:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngForm

But it gives me almost no examples and I am still very confused.  What I would like to do is to have a table with input fields and then check if fields on the table are unchanged? I don't want to include this in a form so I was wondering if I can use ng-form.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form name="itemForm">
<table>
....
</table>
<button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="itemForm.$pristine">
</form>
```

Can I do this with an ng-form directive enclosed in a `DIV` and still set the name in the same way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do it with `ng-form` directive also

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/lnSMmURFNvc3IUoqSE4P?p=preview)